# vba listbox does not return value even when clicked

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a set of VBA listbox (excel-2019) which I populate them from various range on a sheet with code like this

```
LstBx.List() = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Range("E2:E13").Value
```

then I select the first Item with `lstbx.ListIndex = 0` because otherwise clicking on listbox items in runtime throws an error.
After the form loads all listboxes have 1st item selected but the main problem is when I click on the very same item (1st one) no value will be returned. If I select another Item both click and change event will run and values are flowing just fine even if I click the 1st one after I click another item in the list.
Want to know what is happening and how to fix it?

did try click event and change event but no luck

Comment: When do you will the Listboxes? What exact error happens when you don't set `lstbx.ListIndex = 0`?

Comment: Runtime error 94. Invalid use of Null

Comment: I think you need to show more of the code then. Hint: In the VBE-environment, Goto Tool->Options and on the "General" tab, select "Break in Class Module". What exact line throws the error and how is it called?

Comment: I use a procedure to update another listbox based on value selected in said listboxes. So when I click one item in any of the listbox the procedure try to read other listboxes’ values which are not already selected. So I need to have all of them to have at least one item selected.

Comment: The problem is that unless I change the item selected in any of those LBs I will be unable to select the 1st Item.

Answer (score 0):

issue you are facing is that when you select the first item in the listbox using the ListIndex property, the Click event is not triggered because the item is already selected

To fix this, you can set the ListIndex property of the listbox to -1 after populating it with data

```
 LstBx.List() = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Range("E2:E13").Value
    LstBx.ListIndex = -1
```

when you click on an item in the listbox, the Click event will be triggered and you should be able to retrieve its value as expected

Comment: After the `List` is set, `ListIndex` is always -1 , so I don't think this will help the OP. The question is why a runtime error is risen.

Comment: FunThomas is right. The error 94 is risen after I set listindex to -1